# Panning a UIView only from 1 subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView (alertView) that serves as a custom alert. Inside this UIView, I have several pieces of interaction. I would like just the top portion of this custom alert (alertHeaderView) to be able to be panned to move the alertView, while still maintaining the functionality of the alertView contents.

I currently have this half-working. In storyboard, I added the pan gesture recognizer to the whole alertView. My pan functionality works perfect, but it's preventing all the interaction from happening within the view. This is the problem.

```
@IBAction func panAlert(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // ... All my pan code.
}
```

I've created an outlet for the header:

```
@IBOutlet weak var alertHeaderView: UIView!
```

Is there a way I can pan the entire alertView, ONLY from touches from alertHeaderView?

Comment: apply pan gesture to alertHeaderview only

Comment: That makes it pan around only the header. not the entire view.

Comment: you can maintain check in this case by getting touch location inside UIview i.e AlertView if That touch View is in The required Bounds Handle View With Pan Gesture else no Translation, in short Add Pan to whole alert view when User touch The alertView check for the Touch Location and then make translation

Comment: I posted a Answer that will Surely help you getting required Output , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my tried code - it limit the view to be moved from specific location set

```
import UIKit

class AlertWithPan: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var alertView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.alertView.isHidden = true
        self.addPanGesture()
    }

    func addPanGesture()
    {
        let gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(AlertWithPan.handlePanGesture(panGesture:)))
        self.alertView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }



    @objc func handlePanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {

        ///Get my Location
        let touchPosition = panGesture.location(in: self.alertView)
        print("currentTouch: \(touchPosition.y), ViewOrigin_Y: \(String(describing: panGesture.view?.frame.origin.y))")

        //Let us limit the frame Movement on specific location 
        //In your case you had initialised a header View supposingly it is having height 32 
        //So we will set TouchPosition not to move Ahead of that View
        //I am using here touch Location in AlertView 
        //Setting it to limit upto `self.alertView.frame.size.height*0.2`


        //self.alertView.frame.size.height*0.2 - This refers to Height of your Header View 
        //if a view having total height of Hundred then If I write self.alertView.frame.size.height*0.2
        //This means just 20 percent of height - 20 out of hundred 
        //we had added pan in AlertView , I.e So we need to set a proper height in which Pan will be allowed to set translation 
        //self.alertView.frame.size.height*0.2 - using this I made the view to move only in case if touch location is with in the header size I.e 20 
        // if you had provided static height of header 
        //Then Can get this by using like pan gesture.origin.y + header view height 
        // So check will be  touchPosition.y > Total of both
        if touchPosition.y > self.alertView.frame.size.height*0.2 {
            print("High")
        }
        else{
            print("Low")
            ///Get the changes
            let translation = panGesture.translation(in: self.view)

            ///Move view to required Position
            panGesture.view!.center = CGPoint(x: panGesture.view!.center.x, y: panGesture.view!.center.y + translation.y)
            panGesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }



    }


    @IBAction func showMyAlertView(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.alertView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

my Storyboard:

[image]

Working Video :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZZuqxc34BUEZQ7WGFJiA2lU6ydIwqEjn

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm going through your code now, and need a little help here: if touchPosition.y > self.alertView.frame.size.height*0.2 {. I'm not sure what this line is doing. I just want to be able to detect touchPosition within alertHeaderView

Comment: Scratch that, i got it :) I modified that line so the "header area" matches the height of the alertHeaderView, instead of 0.2% of the entire alertView. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I edited my answer with clear Description, Anyhow ,welcome, happy To help

Comment: Thank you for the edited description. That helped. Found a small bug, however. If user taps within content area (area below header), then drags finger up into the "header location", the view jumps up, because finger entered the header area. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes I Noticed that now, I need to check possible Solution for this Will update you if I found some

Comment: Is there any way to use your location conditional check with UIGestureRecognizerState.began? Then you would check the initial placement of the touch, so swiping around fast won't result in unwanted behavior?

Comment: Issue is basically Occurring as Suppose w had Start swiping in inactive area of AlertView pan View gets Activated , Thing is if user s not taking his finger up and reach to active area while swiping it will move View up, Do you have any idea What we can do ? I tried using some gestures in it but didntWorked

Comment: I actually got this solved quite easily. Like Jaydeep commented above, I just added the recognizer to the header. Then i just pan around the alertView center in the handlePanGesture function! I think we were overthinking it :) Works great now

Comment: Exactly , We were overthinking . I too did Will Keep this as Reference for me